# cocoalibspotify SPPlaylistContainer Vs SPPlaylist - can i load the container only to get the flattenplaylists?

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I wrote a program that fetch the userplaylist, 
the problem is with the loading time which is very high (around 20sec)
is there another approach about loading those playlist(userplaylists) ?
i used SPASYNCLOAD to load the container then another SPASYNCLOAD to load the user flatten playlists.
the second SPASYNCLOAD is taking too much time.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playlists will take a long time to load, especially on the first login when there's no cache. Loading all of the playlists at once actually isn't recommended, because if the user has a lot of playlists you need to be careful about memory usage.

The approach you're doing is the correct way to load all the playlists, though. It taking time is expected.

Comment: so basically the loading the container without loading the flatten playlists / playlists will end up with nulls playslits?

Comment: oh.. and on more thing when i'm loading the flatten playlists does it loading the SPTRACK that inside them or only the wrap (SPPlaylist)?